# Why is $e^{tn}(pe^{-t}+q)^n =(qe^t+p)^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in the middle of a stats-related proof and got stuck in an algebraic manipulation.

The source formula goes $$e^{tn}(pe^{-t}+q)^n,$$ and my target result is to simplify that into $$(qe^t+p)^n.$$ I'm not sure how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$e^{tn}=(e^t)^n$;

and $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$.